# How to create similar graph using ggplot in R

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2

The excel sheet Folkhalsomyndigheten_Covid19_Vaccine.xlsx contains statistics on covid-19 vaccinated from 10/6 2022. Tables are saved in different tabs, I'm listing the tabs by:

`readxl::excel_sheets("Folkhalsomyndigheten_Covid19_Vaccine.xlsx")`

The figure below illustrates how vaccination success varies between municipalities in Skåne, Stockholm and Västra Götaland counties based on data in the tab "Vaccinerade kommun och ålder". My goal is to make the corresponding figure.

to avoid the technical notation 2e+05 in the legend for Population, add + scale_size_continuous(labels = scales::label_number()).

vacc_alder <- readxl::read_excel("Folkhalsomyndigheten_Covid19_Vaccine.xlsx",
sheet = "Vaccinerade kommun och ålder")

What figure should look like:
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89wuy.png)

The is link to the data, that is in the tab "Vaccinerade kommun och ålder":
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/rglleg3l1lasb9pyjrxme/Folkhalsomyndigheten_Covid19_Vaccine.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=lrj196v71lg7kacgj2p4xb0gq

This is my code so far:

```
library(ggplot2)

readxl::excel_sheets("Folkhalsomyndigheten_Covid19_Vaccine.xlsx")

vacc_alder <- readxl::read_excel("Folkhalsomyndigheten_Covid19_Vaccine.xlsx", 
                                 sheet = "Vaccinerade kommun och ålder")
```

I need help with how to make the graph in R, using ggplot.

Comment: Here's a good example: https://r-graph-gallery.com/320-the-basis-of-bubble-plot.html

Comment: Hi @Kei Len, glad you were able to solve your problem. Please accept an answer as correct, if it helped, in order to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not identical but can give some idea.

```
library(tidyverse)

vacc_alder <- readxl::read_excel("Folkhalsomyndigheten_Covid19_Vaccine.xlsx", 
                                 sheet = "Vaccinerade kommun och ålder") |> 
  filter(Län_namn %in% c("Norrbottens län", "Skåne län", "Västra Götalands län"))

ggplot(vacc_alder, aes(x = `Andel minst 2 doser`, y = `Andel minst 1 dos`)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Län_namn, size = Befolkning)) + 
  scale_size_continuous(labels = scales::label_number()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1), labels = scales::label_percent()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1), labels = scales::label_percent())
```

PS: If the question is about a graph, it is better to add the code to reproduce the final version of the data that will be used in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example. Simply use color and size in your geom_point aesthetics.

```
library(ggplot2)
        
data(iris)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Petal.Width, color = Species))
```

[image]